# How can I open two completely seperate instances of Excel

Tags: excel

I have two different spreadsheets in Excel that are both macro enabled.  I cut and paste data between them.  Both spreadsheets work very well separately, but when both are open the macro in one of them runs tens or 100's of times slower.

It would appear that two workbooks open in Excel are two different instances, but when looking at the application manager, it is not.  Is there a way to truly have Excel open up as two unique instances?

Comment: I just opened two Excels on my desktop (running Windows 2007), and I see two entries under the Task Manager.

Comment: `start -> run -> excel` x 2

Answer (score 0):

In Office Excel 2007, clicking on the `.exe` file twice opens completely separate tasks in Task Manager.
[image]

Comment: Dang.  I only get the one instance.  I've tried opening the *.exe, from the Start Menu.  Thanks for your help anyway.  It helps to know that it was possible at one time.  My computer is now using 2015 Excel, which is not how I purchased it.  Perhaps this was updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Open an instance of Excel from the Start Menu, NOT the quickstart toolbar, NOT from the File > Open menu.
The second instance of Excel will open in a separate window, not as a different worksheet in the same window